# MFC slider+edit+spinner pattern

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, mfc

In my dialog-based UI that controls an external device I have a bunch of similar looking and behaving "knobs": a triplet of controls consisting of a **slider**, **numeric edit box**, and a **spinner** for that numeric edit box.

A change in value causes a roundtrip to that external device so naturally I'm trying to call that lengthy API only once per "change". The change can come from any of the 3 controls and they have to be in-sync, obviously. What that means in practice is that if an edit box changes - it needs to change the position of a slider. And vise versa.

The API calls are implemented in separate functions that are being called whenever a change in value is reported by the UI framework.

Issues:

1. A straight-forward naïve implementation of the "in-sync" paradigm naturally causes a recursion call when controls start updating each other
2. Introducing a recursion guard (like a `bool m_processingUserInput;`) looks and, frankly, feels quite ugly
3. Making an API call "only" from one type of control and not the other (say only from a slider) is prone to future errors when more controls are added. Plus this approach makes the code look quite messy and (on itself) doesn't solve the recursion problem either

My question is this: am I missing a well-established pattern here that people are using to code this UI interaction? Please, let me know of a way to do this elegantly and efficiently.

Comment: There won't be a recursion because none of the controls you mentioned send the "changed" notification when they are changed programmatically. The notifications are about *user* modifications.

Comment: `SetDlgItemInt(ID, val)` certainly triggers the "on change" handler

Comment: OK, I was wrong about that. That comes from reading MS documentation literally, instead of testing things myself. A recursion guard doesn't sound so bad then. You could do that with a boolean static variable inside of the notification handler and a local variable of a RAII class that sets the static variable to `true` in the constructor and to `false` in the destructor for exception safety and ease of use.

Answer (score 1):

The first control that is changed should fire off a "value updated" event. The other controls should be subscribed to that event and repaint the visual elements in their OnUpdate methods. You can build this on top of the Windows API, or use the MFC's built-in document-view architecture, which is basically their implementation of the model-view-controller pattern:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30291/An-Introduction-to-a-Model-View-Controller-Impleme

Comment: This looks like there will be a whole lot of subclassing to support that model. Or am I misinterpreting the "subscribe to event" methodology?

Comment: It's up to you to decide whether the model is justified based on the complexity of the application. If you are looking for a quick and dirty solution you could always just invalidate the controls that need updating and have them repaint themselves with the new values.

Comment: to cause a repaint with a new value that new value has to be set first, which goes back to the recursion problem I described :(

Comment: ?? The value is set in the first control. There is no recursion. You will have your own controller that will hold the value for all three (or however many you have) controls. This is the quick solution that does not involve using a framework.